# Schema.org/Microdata markup for list of recent posts without providing "author" / "publisher"?

Tags: html, blogs, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

The following code shows a list of links to recent posts on an experimental blog site I am playing with. The problem is that this fails Google's Structured Data Testing Tool because it is missing required items such as `author` and `publisher`.

But I don't want to show these for recent posts and I don't want to show them for every blog post either.  What should I do?  Get rid of the structured data?
Put the required stuff in and hide it with CSS? Or leave as is?

```
<section>
<header>
<h4 class="h4-padding">Recent Posts</h4>
</header>
<ul>
<li>
<article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
<header itemprop="name headline">
<h5><a href="http://myblog.com/post/5/1/2016/a-very-interesting-thing">A very interesting thing</a></h5>
</header>
</article>
</li>
<li>
<article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
<header itemprop="name headline">
<h5><a href="http://myblog.com/post/30/7/2015/something-even-more-interesting">Something event more interesting</a></h5>
</header>
</article>
</li>
<li>
<article itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
<header itemprop="name headline">
<h5><a href="http://myblog.com/something-very-dull">Something very dull</a></h5>
</header>
</article>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s perfectly fine *not* to provide these properties. Schema.org doesn’t require any property.

If Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool says that certain properties are missing, what it really means is:

"If you don’t provide these properties, we won’t show the corresponding Rich Snippet or Knowledge Graph feature in Google Search"

There’s [no need](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58143/17633) to get rid of your structured data just because Google (as one of many consumers) currently doesn’t do something with it. It can be useful for other consumers, and Google may change/introduce features in the future that work with your current set of properties.

Comment: thanks very much for responding. It's difficult to find answers for this kind of stuff.  And it's alarming when google puts big fat red error messages and flags up each missing property as *required*.  But I will stick with what I have for now and see how Google treats it.