# Invalid Schema.org location property in Event

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I'm trying to set schema to my HTML page. The validator (https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) fails at this page:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsEvent">
        <h1 itemprop="name">Event name</h1>
    <p itemprop="description">Some text description ...</p>
    <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2016-03-16T16:00:00+01:00">16.3.</time> - <time itemprop="endDate" datetime="2016-03-20T16:00:00+01:00">20.3.2016</time>
    <span itemprop="location">29-31 Craven Rd,London W2 3BX</span>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see it tells me location address can not be empty.

I also tried to use utils: http://schema-creator.org/event.php
But even I filled all inputs the result was same: "Error invalid location."

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsEvent">
    <a itemprop="url" href="https://www.myevent.com">
        <div itemprop="name"><strong>Me super event</strong>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div itemprop="description">super event
    </div>
    <div>
        <meta itemprop="startDate" content="2016-03-06T12:00">Starts: 03/06/2016 12:00PM
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="endDate" content="2016-03-12:00.000">Ends: 2016-03-12:00.000
</div>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <div itemprop="streetAddress">29-31 Craven Rd,London W2 3BX
    </div>
    <div>
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">London
        </span>, 
        <span itemprop="addressRegion">United kingdom
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone explain me how to specify location?

EDIT: 
As @unor tald me the location must be instance of PostalAddress, so I modified it:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SportsEvent">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Event name</h1>
    <p itemprop="description">Some text description ...</p>
    <time itemprop="startDate" datetime="2016-03-16T16:00:00+01:00">16.3.</time> - <time itemprop="endDate" datetime="2016-03-20T16:00:00+01:00">20.3.2016</time>
    <span itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="streetAddress">29-31 Craven Rd</span>
        <span itemprop="address">29-31 Craven Rd,London W2 3BX</span>
        <span itemprop="name">Test</span>
    </span>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it is still not valid, it looks then address in PostalAddress must be Place, but in Place there must be PostalAddress :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your markup is correct according to Schema.org: the [`location` property](http://schema.org/location) may contain *Text*.

When Google’s SDTT reports an error, it doesn’t necessarily mean that your markup is wrong. Often it [just means that you won’t get one of Google’s search result features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629108/1591669) for your page.

In your case, the error is related to Google’s [Event Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/events). For showing this snippet, Google [requires](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/events#basic_markup_properties) that the `location` property has a `Place` or a `PostalAddress` item as value, but not *Text* (although Google also says "A text string is permitted […]", but their testing tool doesn’t seem to like it).

Your second snippet does that, but it doesn’t nest the `div` with the `location` property in the `div` for the `SportsEvent`, so the location is not associated with the event.

About your third snippet: It seems to be a bug in the testing tool that it requires an `address` property for `PostalAddress` (Schema.org doesn’t define one). If you care about the "errors" the testing tool reports, it should work if you use `Place` as value for `location`, with an `address` that has a `PostalAddress` item as value. It also works if you provide `Place` and use Text in the `address` property:

```
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
  <span itemprop="name">Test</span>
  <span itemprop="address">29-31 Craven Rd, London W2 3BX</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I had used the "address" html tag