# Schema.org type for petition?

Tags: schema.org

I'm looking for something that describes me **a petition** which has:

- Title
- Short description
- Main content
- Author
- Datetime
- Number of signatures
- Signers (people who signed the petition)

  - Name, etc.

I have been searching through `CreativeWork`/`Article`, but it doesn't seem to be semantic, especially that I don't have an `image` which is requered for `Article`.

For now I stucked at http://schema.org/Dataset, but it's just some collection of some data, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Schema.org (as of [version 2.2](https://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.2)) doesn’t provide a type specifically for petitions.

A [**`CreativeWork`**](http://schema.org/CreativeWork) type (like [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article)¹, but probably rather not [`Dataset`](http://schema.org/Dataset)) is suitable for representing the petition document. But unless you want to use the [`contributor`](http://schema.org/contributor) property, there doesn’t seem to be an appropriate property for referencing the signers.

Perhaps the petition itself (in contrast to its document) is of the [**`Intangible`**](http://schema.org/Intangible) type. It’s a stretch (as it’s coming from the e-commerce vocabulary GoodRelations), but maybe the [`Demand`](http://schema.org/Demand) type could be considered:

> A demand entity represents the public, not necessarily binding, not necessarily exclusive, announcement by an organization or person to seek a certain type of goods or services.

The beginning of the definition sounds suitable, it’s only the part with "goods or services" that doesn’t (always) match a petition.

Assuming that `Demand` is appropriate (I’m *not* saying that it is!), the [`seeks`](http://schema.org/seeks) property could be used to reference the `Person` items which represent the persons that signed the petition.

---

¹ Note that the `image` property is not required for an `Article`. Schema.org doesn’t require any properties at all. You probably refer to errors shown in Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool, but [these mean something else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629108/1591669); they are often not errors about your use of Schema.org.