# Different validation results in Structured Data Testing Tool versus Markup Tester

Tags: validation, schema.org, json-ld

So I have the following JSON-LD markup that passes the markup tester (https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/) with no errors but fails the Structured data testing tool (https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) with "ContactPoint must be attached to a parent with a declared type."

As far as I can tell, my ContactPoint is attached to my GovernmentService object. Is there something off that I'm not seeing?

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "GovernmentService",
  "name": "Jibber Jabber",
  "serviceType": "Jabber Application",
  "description": "The Jibber Jabber application is tired of you Jibber jabber!",
  "availableChannel": {
    "@type": "ServiceChannel",
    "serviceUrl": "http://rustled.jimmies.com/",
Error-->"servicePhone":  {
      "@type" : "ContactPoint",
      "telephone" : "+1505890897",
      "name" : "Jabber phone service",
      "contactType": "customer support"
    }
  },
  "url": "http://jibjab.rustled.jimmies.com",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "GovernmentOrganization",
    "name": "Jibbering and Howling",
    "url": "http://desertbluffs.state.az.gov",
    "logo": "http://desertbluffs.state.az.gov/Eagle.gif"
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON-LD seems to be correct and your use of Schema.org seems to be appropriate:

1. [`GovernmentService`](http://schema.org/GovernmentService) can have the `availableChannel` property
2. [`availableChannel`](http://schema.org/availableChannel) expects a `ServiceChannel` value
3. [`ServiceChannel`](http://schema.org/ServiceChannel) can have the `servicePhone` property
4. [`servicePhone`](http://schema.org/servicePhone) expects a `ContactPoint` value

This minimal JSON-LD gives the same error in Google’s SDTT:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "GovernmentService",
  "availableChannel": {
    "@type": "ServiceChannel",
    "servicePhone":  {
      "@type" : "ContactPoint" 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The error message refers to Google’s Knowledge Graph feature [Corporate Contacts](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/contact-points). Unless I’m missing something, this seems to be one of the many cases where an error in Google’s tool [does not mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629108/1591669) that your markup is wrong.

Comment: I figured it was something to do with the tool, since there are others that have had a similar issue where the error should be a warning. I'm just wondering if there is a way to get it to validate so that Google doesn't skip/ignore something I deem important