# Should Schema.org dateModified have some default value if not available?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

For Schema.org [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article) I get an error in https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ for `dateModified`:

> The dateModified field is recommended. Please provide a value if available.

Do I have to write something that I don't have modified date? Because a lot of posts weren't updated. I am unsure if Google is telling me only that it is recommended since there is bright red sign telling me I have an error and this doesn't look promising for my boss who will be checking after me :)

Comment: [Can dateModified be unset on a Schema.org Article, if so when should it be set for the first time?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91536/can-datemodified-be-unset-on-a-schema-org-article-if-so-when-should-it-be-set-f)

Answer (score 1):

The [SDTT](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) is not a general Schema.org validator. It primarily checks the Schema.org-based structured data for Google’s own search result features. If Google’s tool reports an error, it [doesn’t necessarily mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629108/1591669) that your markup is wrong, it often only means that you won’t get a certain Google search result feature.

The vocabulary Schema.org doesn’t require any property. It’s perfectly fine not to provide the [`dateModified` property](http://schema.org/dateModified), and it’s the right thing to do if your publication wasn’t modified yet.

(FWIW, the documentation for Google’s *Top Stories with AMP* feature [says](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/91545/17633), for publications that were not modified, to omit the property or to set it to the same value as `datePublished`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span itemprop='dateModified'>09/05/2017t02:25</span> or
<meta content='09/05/2017t02:25' itemprop='dateModified'/>
<div itemprop='dateModified'>29.05.2017T02:30</div>
```